# Converting addresses to symbol + offset

Tags: windbg

In windbg, is there a way to convert an address to a symbol + offset?

eg:

```
66ef0c17 = MSPTLS!LssbFIsSublineEmpty+0x115f
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ln` (list nearest symbols) should do the trick:

```
0:000> ln 75da78d7 
(75da78c2)   USER32!NtUserGetMessage+0x15   |  (75da78e2)   USER32!GetMessageW
```

Answer (score 3):

`ln` works sometimes, but sometimes it doesn't return the exact symbol. OK for debugging, you can just check, but not optimal for scripting. The best thing I found is using `u` for that, the first line should contain the symbol.

Example, `ln` returns a symbol which translates to `fffff801_1c41000f` instead of `fffff801_1c40f000`:

```
0: kd> ln nt
(fffff801`1c410010)   nt!IoStartNextPacket+0xffffffff`ffffffff   |  (fffff801`1c41004c)   nt!IopStartNextPacketByKeyEx

0: kd> ? nt!IoStartNextPacket+0xffffffff`ffffffff
Evaluate expression: -8791324033009 = fffff801`1c41000f
```

`u` returns the correct symbol, `nt+0x0` (even though the output is knida convoluted):

```
0: kd> u nt L1
nt!IoStartNextPacket <PERF> (nt+0x0):
fffff801`1c40f000 4d5a            pop     r10
```